# CPanel : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: sql, cpanel

I'm getting this error over and over again. I'm using CPanel.

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My code in connection file:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=mydomain_xxx;host=localhost';
$user = 'mydomain_yyy';
$password = 'password';
```

Comment: are you connecting remote server database using `root` username?

Comment: How do you connect to the database? It seems that you are not passing the `$user` and `$password` correctly.

Comment: I don't know much about servers/databases. I'm just writing this code and uploading on the CPanel server. I've made the corresponding database and user and given the privileges. Still, it is not working.

Comment: @user188995 You probably connect to your database somehow. Show us that part of the code. If you're using PDO you probably have something like `$db = new PDO(...)`.